# Find the name of the minimum price beer that can be found at any bar

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following relation from the Bars and Beers database:

sells (bar, beer, price): indicates the price of each beer sold at each bar (note that each bar can sell many beers and many bars can sell the same beer, at possibly different prices).

The following query finds the name of the minimum price beer that can be found at any bar.

```
SELECT s.beer
FROM sells s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT si.beer
FROM sells si
WHERE si.price <= s.price)
```

Hi, I am learning sql slowly and I am having trouble understanding the part "si.price <= s.price". Wouldn't the entire query always return an empty table since the nested select is basically comparing the same two tables?

Comment: i can give you the answer without a database :D

Comment: The answer is already there I am just trying to understand it.

Comment: Put some data into a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), as it makes it easier to see what's what and to explore your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in that query - it will never return any rows, because no price is not equal to itself.

To work, it should be:

```
...
WHERE si.price < s.price)
```

Assuming that change is made, the explanation of how it works s that the inner query executes once for every row in the table and depends on the outer table (called a "co-related subquery"). Because the same table is used in the inner query, you need to alias the outer table (as "s" in this case). The inner query asserts that there is no (other) price lower than the price in the row being executed.

Incidentally, aliasing the inner query is unnecessary - you could remove "s1" and it would still work, because the inner query is the default scope:

```
SELECT beer
FROM sells s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sells  -- no alias needed
    WHERE price <= s.price)
```

Further, this is a "bad" query because of the corelated subquery, which causes "n" queries to execute (one for each row). You're better off using the `min()` aggregate function:

```
SELECT beer
FROM sells
WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM sells)
```

Apart from this query being simpler and easier to understand (two good things), it executes faster because only two queries are executed (one subquery to find the minimum price, and one to get the whole row that has it).

Finally, the last (albeit minor) bug is that all of these will return multiple rows if there are multiple low-priced beers with the same price. To return **the** lowest price beer, you would need to limit the number of rows to 1 and decide how to break the tie (perhaps on name). In fact, returning just one row allows for an even simpler query:

```
select beer
FROM sells
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 1
```

And if you needed to consistently break a tie (ie not return a *random* same-priced beer with the same lowest price), also order by the name:

```
select beer
FROM sells
ORDER BY price, beer
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is a great explanation thank you so much. This made it clearer to me now.

Comment: No problem. You can but me that beer one day :)

Comment: Slight error query 2 should be `SELECT s.beer
FROM sells s
  WHERE price = (SELECT min(price) FROM sells)`

Comment: @davidstrachan thanks. actually, the "s." is not needed anywhere - I've changed it to `SELECT beer` in all queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.beer, s.price
FROM sells s
GROUP BY s.beer
HAVING s.price = MIN(s.price)
```

FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f292c/1

Please note that this is not standard. Mysql allows to not group by the selected columns.

Answer (score 1):

The nested query is comparing the same two tables.  But, it is really more like taking one row from the table, comparing it to all the others in the table, and then moving on to the next row.  This is a *conceptual* explanation.  The actual implementation might be quite different.

However, the query as written will return nothing, because of the `<=`.  This should be `<`.

However, there is a much simpler way to write this query:

```
select *
from sells
order by price
limit 1
```

Best of luck on learning SQL.

Comment: No, that will return all the records sorted by price, not the lowest price in each bar.

Comment: @MarlinPierce I think the OP wanted the lowest price across all bars, not the lowest price for each bar... I'm basing this on the intention of his attempted query.

Comment: The question says " the minimum price beer that can be found at any bar" not " the minimum price beer that can be found at each bar".  Plus, the example query comes close to finding the minimum across all bars.  I stand by my interpretation, unless the questioner clarifies the point.

Answer (score 0):

Just ORDER BY the price in an ascending fashion and LIMIT the result set to one item:

```
SELECT bar, beer, price FROM sells ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That would be the lowest price in *ANY* bar, not each lowest price in *EVERY* bar.

Comment: @MarlinPierce The question asks for lowest price beer at ANY bar not the lowest priced beer at each bar.